# First character of each array element

Tags: arrays, bash

Given this array

```
foo=(123 456 789)
```

I would like to create a new variable that consists of the first character of
each element. This works for the previous array

```sh
bar=${foo[*]/%??}
```

but I would prefer a solution that works with different length elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
echo "${foo[@]%[0-9][0-9]}"
1 4 7
```

Or storing them into an array:

```
bar=("${foo[@]%[0-9][0-9]}")

declare -p bar
declare -a bar='([0]="1" [1]="4" [2]="7")'
```

#### UPDATE

**Alternative method using `printf`** for variable length input elements:

```
foo=(1344423 4876556 78945)
bar=( $(printf "%1.1s\n" "${foo[@]}") )

declare -p bar
declare -a bar='([0]="1" [1]="4" [2]="7")'
```

Comment: Nice. `printf "%1.1s\n"` can be further simplified to `printf "%c\n"`

Answer (score 4):

Use a `for` loop:

```
bar=()
for f in "${foo[@]}" ; do
    bar+=( ${f:0:1} )
done
```

Creates `bar=(1 4 7)`. If you just want a string instead, remove the parentheses:

```
    bar+=${f:0:1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS=$'\n' awk NF=1 FPAT=. ORS= <<< "${foo[*]}"
```

Result

```
147
```

Comment: Oops, lol. It didn't show that in the VLQ. (But you should still probably explain that code.)